# How to use pooling with node-persist?

Tags: node.js, connection-pooling, node-persist

Is pooling enabled by default, or does it have to be manually enabled?

Could someone provide a `database.json` or similar example of how to enable/disable pooling?

https://github.com/nearinfinity/node-persist#connectionPoolingUsing

Answer (score 1):

Pooling is not enabled by default, and needs to be manually enabled by specifying the `pooling` option and a pooling `name`.

You can verify this by looking at the code for `connect` in [persist.js](https://github.com/nearinfinity/node-persist/blob/master/lib/persist.js):

```
if (opts.pooling && opts.pooling.name) {
  ... // Pooling is setup here
  return pool.acquire(connectAfterAutoDefinesComplete.bind(this, callback));
} else {
  return driver.connect(opts, connectAfterAutoDefinesComplete.bind(this, callback));
}
```

---

To answer your question directly:

You may enable pooling by providing the options as specified in the linked example, and you would disable pooling by not providing these options in your `database.json`.